# display line breaks( \r\n )

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm really confused now. I am trying to display line breaks to a view by using 
`echo nl2br($text)`.

I saved the text using the `Sanitize::clean( $text, array('carriage'=>false) )`

I viewed the text saved in the database and it is saved properly. I see linebreaks being translated to `\r\n`, `'` to `&rsquo;`, etc..

what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Weird... What happens when you, say, print to file or stdout?

My knee jerk is to ask what happens when you print (as opposed to echo). What about debug()?

Comment: Data is sanitized anyway when saved using the standard CakePHP mechanisms -- you may be doubling up on your sanitization? The [book](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1187/clean) says that all options are enabled by default so you perhaps it is safer/easier for your purposes to use something like `str_replace("\r", "", $text)` to normalize carriage returns?

Comment: I'm sorry.. I had the carriage set to true here but what I did was I set it to false. I also tried debug and print but it still displays the \r\n..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dont use Sanitize

its totally unnecessary

simply save it and display it afterwards with

```
echo nl2br(h($text));
```

Comment: Nice...it worked.. I guess I should've not bothered myself from the start..I did not know that Cakephp automatically cleans all inputs.. Thanks very much..